# How to change the height of an accordionSummary in react?

Tags: reactjs, height, accordion

I am trying to alter the height of an accordionSummary bar in React and cannot find a way to do it. It has to be an inline css as it is used only once. Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

just pass height inside `style` object like this:

```
style={{height: '200px'}}
```

wherever you are using element.

Comment: It's the first thing I tried but the accordionSummary height remains unchanged.

Comment: Then set height of the content inside accordionSummary.

Comment: If inner content consist different components then put them inside `div` and set height.

Answer (score 0):

try add (adjust the max and min height of the object as well)

```
sx={{ minHeight: 30, height: 30 }}
```